# bad quality of a surface content after scaling or as a result of Z-translate with perspective option

Tags: famo.us

```
var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
mainContext.setPerspective(500);

var surface = new Surface({
    content: 'im a content',
    size: [200, 200]
});
var modifier = new StateModifier();
mainContext.add(modifier).add(surface);
```

in onClick event the following code results in very bad quality of displayed content 'im a content':
1) `modifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 0, 300));`
or
2) `modifier.setTransform(Transform.scale(3, 3, 1));`

What Im doing wrong here?
How to force famo.us to rerender content after transformations for better quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much an issue of Famo.us as it is the browser. **[See the issue here.](https://github.com/Famous/famous/issues/551)**
Windows Chrome browser?

**[I tested it using this code. Example jsBin](http://jsbin.com/cigewi/1/edit?js,output)**

- Chrome (39.0.2171.95) **Not Working**
- Firefox (31) **Working**
- IE (11.0.15) **Working**

```js
  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

  var surface = new Surface({
    content: 'Famous Application',
    size: [200, 200],
    transform: Transform.scale(1, 1, 1),
    properties: {
      fontSize: '2em',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
    }
  });
  var modifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0, 0],
    align: [0, 0]
  });
  mainContext.add(modifier).add(surface);

  surface.on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if (!surface.clicked) {
      //modifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 0, 300));
      modifier.setTransform(Transform.scale(3, 3, 1), {duration: 300}, function(){surface.setContent('');surface.setContent('<div>Scaled Now!</div>');});

    }
    else {
      modifier.setTransform(Transform.scale(1, 1, 1), {duration: 300}, function(){surface.setContent('');surface.setContent('Famous Application');});
    }
    surface.clicked = !surface.clicked;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there at least a workaround for chrome? I need it crossbrowser

Comment: You may want to consider [using proportion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767706/famo-us-using-proportionsfrom-in-modifiers/27769632#27769632) rather than scale, but you would not be able to transition :(

Comment: as a workaround maybe it's possible to convert text to canvas and operate with an image OR to handle font size 'by hand' using surface css options?